# Using scanLeft on a map of lists in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a map like this:

```
val dummy = Map("1992" -> List("1", "2"), "1993" -> List("4", "5"))
```

I am trying to merge the lists as I go along from left to right in the map. So, my desired result would look like:

```
val result = Map("1992" -> List("1", "2"), "1993" -> List("1", "2", "4", "5"))
```

I tried to use `scanLeft` to achieve this, but I can't get the code to run correctly:

```
def mergeNodes(tuple1: (String, List[String]), tuple2: (String, List[String])): (String, List[String]) =
    (tuple2._1, tuple1._2 ++ tuple2._2)

val dummy = Map("1992" -> List("1", "2"), "1993" -> List("4", "5"))
val res = dummy.scanLeft[(String, List[String])](("", List[String].empty))(mergeNodes)
```

But it gives the following error:

> missing argument list for method mergeNodes

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *"from left to right in the map"* - where is the "left" and "right" in a `Map`? Is this an insertion-order preserving map or a sorted map?

Comment: [works for me](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/F6PCO77zQW6roRXi3stpPg) after fixing the syntax 

Comment: `Maps` don't have order so the question is a bit unclear, you mean to use a `SortedMap´ by its key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the pattern-matching approach to be
a bit more legible:

```
val m = Map("1992" -> List("1", "2"), "1993" -> List("4", "5"))
val res = m
  .scanLeft("not-a-key" -> List.empty[String]){
    case ((_, acc), (k, v)) => (k, acc ++ v)
  }
  .tail
  .toMap
```

In each step, you drop the previous key, take the new key, and combine the accumulated entries with the new value.

Produces:

```
Map(1992 -> List(1, 2), 1993 -> List(1, 2, 4, 5))
```

I'm not too convinced about the order, though (`Map`s of size 2 are too small to be scrambled randomly). Maybe it's safer to convert it to a sorted list first.